# Prevent same google font being loaded more than once

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I notice that exactly the same google font is being loaded twice on my website:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed%3A400%2C+700&ver=4.6.1

How can I ensure that the font is only loaded once? I have dequeued all google font scripts apart from my main theme'google fonts' but this is still a problem.

Thank you

Comment: If you've dequeued all the google fonts calls then I'd guess that it's added without enqueueing or hardcoded in somewhere. Try searching your theme and plugin files for the string `fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed` to see where it shows.

Comment: William is correct. It could also be set asynchronously with JS. Searching the theme and plugin files is the right approach.

Comment: Thank you, have managed to reduce to one instance by just preserving headings and body font whilst dequeueing the main theme font call.